# const TYPE& - when I will want to use by reference to const?

Tags: c++

I read about `reference variable` in cpp, and I don't understand when I will want to use with reference to const? for what it's good?

Comment: Lets say that `TYPE` is something you don't want to (or even *can*) copy, and you don't want to modify it either, then passing it as a reference to `const` is a great solution. Furthermore, it's not possible for non-constant references to bind to temporary objects or values.

Comment: You will want to use it almost all the time. Well explained in the "Effective C++" book, Chapter 4, Item 20, page 86.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so according to what you say, it's for declare that I don't want to modify the value of it?

Comment: `const TYPE&` is used so often, it should have it's own key in the keyboard. Just like php needs `$` key to avoid holding down shit :)

Comment: That's *one* of the reasons yes.

Comment: Questions like this highlight that non-const as default was wrong - and that it's non-const functions and objects that should be declared.  You may find that you get a more concise answer by asking "when should I not use const" rather than "when should I use const"; or "when should I pass by copy rather than reference"

Comment: @UKMonkey Amazing advice, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a reference when you either don't want to copy the parameter or want to alter the original rather than a copy local to the scope of the function.

Use const when you do want the parameter to be constant during the duration of the function.

So then use a const reference when you both do not want to copy the parameter but do not want to alter it.

For example:

```
void print_vector(const std::vector<std::string>& strvector) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strvector.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << strvector[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This method only `cout`'s every string in a vector. It would be wasteful to copy the entire vector, thus the `&`. But you don't want to alter the vector passed as a parameter either, thus the `const`.

Comment: So it's just a matter of declartion that I don't going to alter it?

Comment: @Jor.Mal Well, not entirely - you wouldn't be able to alter passed in object if you passed it by value either. The not copying of large objects, when it isn't needed, aspect of it is more important.

Comment: Const correctness is also very important for self-documentation. You can tell immediately from the prototype of a function that it won't modify a parameter. And if you accidentally try to change it the compiler will tell you.

Comment: @Jor.Mal It is more than declaration. The `&` changes totally the nature of what is passed to the function, a reference to an object versus a copy of it. The `const` will cause your compiler to prohibit you from altering it within the function.